# How to read if a checkbox is checked in PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms, post, checkbox

How to read if a checkbox is checked in PHP?

Comment: This question actually means "*was* checked" (when the form was submitted). PHP determining if a checkbox **is** checked would require an Ajax call once the element was toggled.

Answer (score 408, accepted):

If your HTML page looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="value1">
```

After submitting the form you can check it with:

```
isset($_POST['test'])
```

or

```
if ($_POST['test'] == 'value1') ...
```

Comment: Checkboxes can also have value `on`, when they are checked. Therefore for compatibility it's easier just to use `isset($_POST['checkboxName'])`.

Comment: The "on" value may be supported by some browsers when value attribute is not set, but in general it is better to set the value attribute and to check for it on submit.

Comment: Does the 'Value1' change if the box is checked?

Comment: @Developer_ACE Unless I'm misunderstanding you, the value in this example would be `value1` if the checkbox is checked. If it's not checked, `$_POST['test']` would simply not exist.

Comment: if using serialize to submit do this.       var checkbox1_data = $("#checkboxinput_id").prop("checked")==false?"0":"1";
var data = $("#formveri").serialize()+"&a="+checkbox1_data;

Answer (score 124):

Zend Framework use a nice hack on checkboxes, which you can also do yourself:

Every checkbox generated is associated with a hidden field of the same name, placed just before the checkbox, and with a value of "0". Then if your checkbox as the value "1", you'll always get the '0' or '1' value in the resulting GET or POST

```
<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="1">
```

Comment: I also noticed about that, but I feel safe to use it: Zend Framework does it too!

Comment: This is interesting. But is there a tiny possibility that the user agent might submit the first value instead of the last, assuming the checkbox is checked?

Comment: @rybo111, for the user agent i don't think so, but for a custom javascript form parser you should take care.

Comment: Sorry, could someone explain me how does it work? I didn't understand. Why that hidden field if only the last value is always submitted (the `input[type="checkbox"]`'s one)?

Comment: when the checkbox is unchecked it's not transmitted in the post (so only the hidden is transmitted). When it's checked it is transmitted, and will overwrite the hidden value.

Comment: i really cant belive this is working. What a damn situation. Checkboxes is wrong designed so. Thank u for your answer.

Answer (score 60):

When using checkboxes as an array:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="food[]" value="Orange">
<input type="checkbox" name="food[]" value="Apple">
```

You should use `in_array()`:

```
if(in_array('Orange', $_POST['food'])){
  echo 'Orange was checked!';
}
```

Remember to check the array is set first, such as:

```
if(isset($_POST['food']) && in_array(...
```

Comment: checkboxes as an array and `foreach ($_POST['food'] as $selected_food)` to work on checked one is nice, thanks

Answer (score 41):

Let your html for your checkbox will be like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check1">
```

Then after submitting your form you need to check like

```
if (isset($_POST['check1'])) {

    // Checkbox is selected
} else {

   // Alternate code
}
```

Assuming that `check1` should be your checkbox name.And if your form submitting method is `GET` then you need to check with `$_GET` variables like

```
if (isset($_GET['check1'])) {

   // Checkbox is selected
}
```

Answer (score 27):

```
$check_value = isset($_POST['my_checkbox_name']) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: very fast and very clever

Comment: best solution I have seen

Comment: `(int)isset($_POST['my_checkbox_name'])`  would do exactly the same!

Answer (score 11):

I've been using this trick for several years and it works perfectly without any problem for checked/unchecked checkbox status while using with PHP and Database.

HTML Code: (for Add Page)

```
<input name="status" type="checkbox" value="1" checked>
```

Hint: remove `checked` if you want to show it as unchecked by default

HTML Code: (for Edit Page)

```
<input name="status" type="checkbox" value="1" 
<?php if ($row['status'] == 1) { echo "checked='checked'"; } ?>>
```

PHP Code: (use for Add/Edit pages)

```
$status = $_POST['status'];
if ($status == 1) {
$status = 1;
} else {
$status = 0;
}
```

Hint: There will always be empty value unless user checked it. So, we already have PHP code to catch it else keep the value to 0. Then, simply use the $status variable for database.

Comment: this is the really good form to do this in pure simple php. but have to note that the value of a checkbox is string on when it is activated an a inexisting value if it is checked.

Answer (score 8):

To check if a checkbox is checked use **empty()**

When the form is submitted, the checkbox will **ALWAYS** be set, because **ALL *POST*** variables will be sent with the form.

Check if checkbox is checked with empty as followed:

```
//Check if checkbox is checked    
if(!empty($_POST['checkbox'])){
 #Checkbox selected code
} else {
 #Checkbox not selected code
}
```

Comment: If the checkbox is unchecked it will not be posted so it will NOW ALWAYS be set.

Comment: ^ NOT* always be set

Comment: @WessamElMahdy Right, that's the point of using `empty()`. It will check if the variable exists and is not empty without throwing an error if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the corresponding value as being set and non-empty in either the $_POST or $_GET array depending on your form's action.

i.e.: With a POST form using a `name` of "test" (i.e.: `<input type="checkbox" name="test">` , you'd use:

```
if(isset($_POST['test']) {
   // The checkbox was enabled...

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with the short if:

```
$check_value = isset($_POST['my_checkbox_name']) ? 1 : 0;
```

or with the new PHP7 `Null coalescing operator`

```
$check_value = $_POST['my_checkbox_name'] ?? 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Learn about `isset` which is a built in "function" that can be used in if statements to tell if a variable has been used or set

Example:

```
    if(isset($_POST["testvariabel"]))
     {
       echo "testvariabel has been set!";
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, the above examples work only when you want to INSERT a value, not useful for UPDATE different values to different columns, so here is my little trick to update:

```
//EMPTY ALL VALUES TO 0 
$queryMU ='UPDATE '.$db->dbprefix().'settings SET menu_news = 0, menu_gallery = 0, menu_events = 0, menu_contact = 0';
            $stmtMU = $db->prepare($queryMU);
            $stmtMU->execute();
if(!empty($_POST['check_menus'])) {
    foreach($_POST['check_menus'] as $checkU) {
try {
//UPDATE only the values checked
    $queryMU ='UPDATE '.$db->dbprefix().'settings SET '.$checkU.'= 1';
            $stmtMU = $db->prepare($queryMU);
            $stmtMU->execute();  
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
          $msg = 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();}

        }
}
```

```
<input type="checkbox" value="menu_news" name="check_menus[]" />
<input type="checkbox" value="menu_gallery" name="check_menus[]" />
```

....

The secret is just update all VALUES first (in this case to 0), and since the  will only send the checked values, that means everything you get should be set to 1, so everything you get set it to 1.

Example is PHP but applies for everything.

Have fun :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$is_checked = isset($_POST['your_checkbox_name']) &&
              $_POST['your_checkbox_name'] == 'on';
```

[Short circuit evaluation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) will take care so that you don't access `your_checkbox_name` when it was not submitted.

Answer (score 1):

A minimalistic boolean check with switch position retaining

```
<?php

$checked = ($_POST['foo'] == ' checked');

?>

<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value=" checked"<?=$_POST['foo']?>>
```

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one. This is especially true when answering a *VERY* old post 11 other answers.

Comment: It's good you recognize the need for the checkbox to retain its state. However, your code to do this is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

  if (isset($_POST['add'])) {

    $nama      = $_POST['name'];
    $subscribe = isset($_POST['subscribe']) ? $_POST['subscribe'] : "Not Checked";

    echo "Name: {$nama} <br />";
    echo "Subscribe: {$subscribe}";

    echo "<hr />";   

  }

?>

<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST" >

  <input type="text" name="name" /> <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="subscribe" value="news" /> News <br />

  <input type="submit" name="add" value="Save" />

</form>
```

Comment: can you explain your goal here?

Answer (score 1):

```
<form>
<input type="check" id=chk1 value="1">
<input type="check" id=chk2 value="1">
<input type="check" id=chk3 value="1">
</form>
```

when you check on chk2 you can see values as:

```
<?php
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{
    if(isset($key))
        $$key=strip_tags($value);
}
insert into table (chk1,chk2,chk3) values ('','1','');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

in BS3 you can put

```
  <?php
                  $checked="hola";
                  $exenta = $datosOrdenCompra[0]['exenta'];
                  var_dump($datosOrdenCompra[0]['exenta']);
                  if(isset($datosOrdenCompra[0]['exenta']) and $datosOrdenCompra[0]['exenta'] == 1){

                      $checked="on";

                  }else{
                    $checked="off";
                  }

              ?>
              <input type="checkbox" id="exenta" name="exenta" <?php echo $checked;?> > <span class="label-text"> Exenta</span>
```

**Please Note** the usage of `isset($datosOrdenCompra[0]['exenta'])`

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress have the `checked()` function.
Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/checked/

```
checked( mixed $checked, mixed $current = true, bool $echo = true )
```

Description
Compares the first two arguments and if identical marks as checked

Parameters
$checked
(mixed) (Required) One of the values to compare

$current
(mixed) (Optional) (true) The other value to compare if not just true
Default value: true

$echo
(bool) (Optional) Whether to echo or just return the string
Default value: true

Return #Return
(string) html attribute or empty string

Answer (score 0):

i have fixed it into a PHP form with a checkbox

$categories = get_terms( ['taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'hide_empty' => false] );
foreach ($categories as $categorie) {
echo "<input type="checkbox" value="$categorie->term_taxonomy_id" name="catselected[]"> $categorie->slug";
}

This way i add it to the Woocommerce tabel.
wp_set_post_terms( $product_id, $_POST['catselected'], 'product_cat' );

Answer (score -1):

filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'checkbox_name', FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY)

Answer (score -3):

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['nameCheckbox'])){
    $_SESSION['fr_nameCheckbox'] = true;
}

?>

<input type="checkbox" name="nameCheckbox" 

<?php 

if(isset($_SESSION['fr_nameCheckbox'])){
    echo 'checked'; 
    unset($_SESSION['fr_nameCheckbox']);
} 

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Answer (score -3):

you should give name to your input .
then which box is clicked you will receive 'on' in your choose method

```
Array
(
    [shch] => on
    [foch] => on
    [ins_id] => #
    [ins_start] => شروع گفتگو
    [ins_time] => ما معمولاً در چند دقیقه پاسخ میدهیم
    [ins_sound] => https://.../media/sounds/ding-sound-effect_2.mp3
    [ins_message] => سلام % به کمک نیاز دارید؟
    [clickgen] => 
)
```

i have two checked box in my form name with 'shch' and 'foch'