# How to find value of checkboxes in PHP?

Tags: php, checkbox

I followed the suggestion in this post:
[How to read if a checkbox is checked in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554758/how-to-read-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-php)

I am trying to get values of checkboxes in form. I have tried separating the conditionals and using them together like this, checking isset and trying to get value. Either way it always returns "NO". What am I doing wrong?

```
if (isset($_POST['sign']) && $_POST['sign'] == 'yes-checked-sign')  {
    $check2 = "YES";
} else {
    $check2 = "NO";
}

<input type="checkbox" name="sign" value = "yes-checked-sign" />
```

Comment: Are you POSTing the form to the page with the check?

Comment: Try removing the spaces between value and "yes-checked-sign".

Comment: You have more than only one checkbox, right? It's impossible, this code given, to get FALSE. You either get "YES" or "NO"

Comment: checkboxes which weren't set in the form are NOT submitted with the rest of the form. you don't have to explicitly compare values: the mere presence of the checkbox's name in $_POST means it was checked.

Comment: Thanks Reflic, I tried removing spaces, didn't make any difference. Marc B, seems like just checking and not comparing explicitly should work, but not here.

Comment: @djot, I meant "NO", not false. Sorry, since edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking for `isset($_POST['sign'])` should be sufficient.

Make sure the [`checkbox`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.checkbox.html#input.checkbox) is surrounded by a [`form`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/form.html#form) element because you might be not actually [*`POST`ing*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.5) it.

```
<form method="POST" action="foo.php">
<!-- Your checkbox goes here. -->
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Campari. Yes the form is POSTing correctly and surrounded by the form element. I have more than one checkbox, the other one set to a different value and checked with a similar conditional. Unfortunately, isset($_POST['sign']) isn't sufficient for some reason. It's false even when checked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For checking if checkbox is checked:

```
if (isset($_POST['sign']))  {
    $check2 = "YES";
} else {
    $check2 = "NO";
}
```

Form with pre-checked checkbox:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="sign" checked/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Hope this helps.