# php checkbox insert 0 if not check

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a checkbox in PHP and I would like to have it checked if the value of the checkbox in the database is 1 and insert "0"  in the database if saved and not checked

sample checkbox

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="chckpagibigcon" <?php 
            if(isset($_POST['chckpagibigcon'])){
                echo 'checked value = "0"';
            }else{
                echo 'value = "1"';
            }
            ?>>
```

Comment: change `echo 'checked value = "0"';` to `echo 'value = "0"';` :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554758/how-to-read-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-php

This gives you the information.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty good solution would be:

```
<input type='hidden' name='chckpagibigcon' value='0'/>
<input type='checkbox' name='chckpagibigcon' value='1' <?php echo (isset($_POST['chckpagibigcon']))?'checked':'';?>/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chckpagibigcon" <?php 
                                if(isset($_POST['chckpagibigcon'])){
                                    echo 'checked value = "1"';
                                }else{
                                    echo 'value = "0"';
                                }
                                ?>>
```

Just revers your condition.

Comment: don't forget that you need a submit button with the form though to properly pass the post variables