# get all checkbox values whether it is checked or not checked in php

Tags: php, checkbox

I want all the checkbox value in another page (whether it is checked or not).
I want to find which image is default.

I tried

```
<input class="image_close" style="float: right;" type="checkbox" name="make_default[]" value="1" title="Make Default">
```

but in this code, I get only check checkbox value. I can't find which is checked.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read if a checkbox is checked in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554758/how-to-read-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-php)

Comment: You don't need "[]" in the name. If multiple checkbox have this name, it will become an array in the DOM...

Answer (score 0):

You should not give name as `make_default[]` but give different names like image1,image2 etc..

so that by taking input as post on another page,you will come to know which fields are checked.....