# Adding a field to a file based on checkbox value

Tags: php, checkbox

I am doing a PHP assignment where I am getting input that uses some checkboxes and stores the information in a file.

Let's say I have a checkbox

```
 Active: <input type="checkbox" name="preference" value="Pepperoni" checked="checked>
```

When I say something like:

```
$Preference1 = $_POST['preference'];
```

What is stored in `$Preference1`? Does it store information that tells whether the box was checked or not, or does it contain `"Pepperoni"`? Is there a way to check to see if a box is checked? Like,

```
Pesudocode

if Preference1 is checked
   add Pepperoni to the file;

if Preference2 is checked
   add Sausage to the file;
```

I did work with radio buttons but those are a bit different since only one of those can be checked at a time, but for checkboxes, multiples boxes and be selected. Is there a way to see if a button is checked and if so, how would I do that? Thanks.

**UPDATE** After doing some digging around I found a post that did something like this:

```
$('#isAgeSelected').attr('checked')
```

But that is using jQuery. Would something like the `.attr` work in PHP? Could I say something like

```
if($_POST['preference'].attr("checked"))
   //do whatever
```

Does this work in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can try with store values into an single array. So you can track with multiple value that has been checked.

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) &&  $_POST['submit']== 'submit'){
    if(isset($_POST['preference']) && count($_POST['preference']>0)){
        echo"<pre>";print_r($_POST['preference']);
    } else {
        echo "Empty";
    }

}

?>
<form name='myForm' method='post'>
<input type="checkbox" name="preference[]" value="Pepperoni" >
<input type="checkbox" name="preference[]" value="Pepperoni1" >
<input type="checkbox" name="preference[]" value="Pepperoni2">
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554758/how-to-read-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-php). Something like:

```
if (isset($_POST['preference'])) {

    // Checkbox is selected
} else {

   // Alternate code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$Preference1 = $_POST['preference'] = "**Pepperoni**"  //value from < input > tag

To check if box is checked, you have to check if $_POST['preference'] is set and is not NULL.

```
if (isset($_POST['preference'])) {
    echo "Checkbox is selected";
}
```