# I want to give a permission like yes or no using checkbox...so could I handle that..using php

Tags: php, checkbox

[image: System Page]

This is my system page which is in form and after saving the form so in server side how can I handle permissions one by one?

[image: db Table]

This is my db-table structure according that how can I handle that logic?

Answer (score 0):

You need another table that indexes the SEQUENCES (from the systems page). Do you have it? If not, create table SEQUENCES:

```
id | name | category | description
1 | Select File | Archiving Service | user can select a file...
2 | Search Files | Archiving Service | user can .....
```

Create a PHP processing file that: gets user form form and finds him in the database; gets user's permissions from the form and stores them in the db with the ID from the SEQUENCES table

(example: in the CREATE column put all the id's from the SEQUENCES table, depending on the checked checkboxes)

```
user_right_id | create | modify | ....
user_1 | 1,2 | 1 | ...
```

(user_1 can create: select files, search files)

(user_1 can modify: select files)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here. Are you asking for the code to process the checkboxes and insert the correct values in the database?

Comment: If you need to learn how to process checkboxes from HTML in PHP, start with this guide: [guide about checkbox & php](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html) or this one: [stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554758/how-to-read-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-php)