# Explode database string and compare value with another string in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, if-statement, explode

I'm stucked in a part of my project where I need to compare the checkbox input i got in my database with another value.

I need to split the input using explode and compare each of the values to see if any of them matches with a list of inputs. If any of them  does, I want to echo the values of the ones that matches.

Splitting the input worked but comparing isn't working. Below is my code.

```
            <?php
            $cou = explode(',' , $row_rsCourse['courses']);
            foreach($cou as $mark){
                $mark1 = $mark."<br>";
                    }

                if ($mark1 = $row_rsCourselist['code'] ){echo $row_rsCourselist['name'];}else {echo "Failed";}
            ?>


                /*
                For example: 
                $row_rsCourse['courses'] = (a,b,d,g,i)
                $row_rsCourselist['code'] = is a database column which contains letters a - z in different input
                $row_rsCourselist['name'] = is a database column which contains names from a - z in different inputs e.g (Andre Ben Charlie etc)
                */
```

BELOW IS THE FULL SOURCE CODE

```
                <?php require_once('Connections/dbConnect.php'); ?>
                <?php
                //initialize the session
                if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
                  session_start();
                }

                // ** Logout the current user. **
                $logoutAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?doLogout=true";
                if ((isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) && ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] != "")){
                  $logoutAction .="&". htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
                }

                if ((isset($_GET['doLogout'])) &&($_GET['doLogout']=="true")){
                  //to fully log out a visitor we need to clear the session varialbles
                  $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = NULL;
                  $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = NULL;
                  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = NULL;
                  unset($_SESSION['MM_Username']);
                  unset($_SESSION['MM_UserGroup']);
                  unset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']);

                  $logoutGoTo = "index.php";
                  if ($logoutGoTo) {
                    header("Location: $logoutGoTo");
                    exit;
                  }
                }
                ?>
                <?php
                if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
                  session_start();
                }
                $MM_authorizedUsers = "";
                $MM_donotCheckaccess = "true";

                // *** Restrict Access To Page: Grant or deny access to this page
                function isAuthorized($strUsers, $strGroups, $UserName, $UserGroup) { 
                  // For security, start by assuming the visitor is NOT authorized. 
                  $isValid = False; 

                  // When a visitor has logged into this site, the Session variable MM_Username set equal to their username. 
                  // Therefore, we know that a user is NOT logged in if that Session variable is blank. 
                  if (!empty($UserName)) { 
                    // Besides being logged in, you may restrict access to only certain users based on an ID established when they login. 
                    // Parse the strings into arrays. 
                    $arrUsers = Explode(",", $strUsers); 
                    $arrGroups = Explode(",", $strGroups); 
                    if (in_array($UserName, $arrUsers)) { 
                      $isValid = true; 
                    } 
                    // Or, you may restrict access to only certain users based on their username. 
                    if (in_array($UserGroup, $arrGroups)) { 
                      $isValid = true; 
                    } 
                    if (($strUsers == "") && true) { 
                      $isValid = true; 
                    } 
                  } 
                  return $isValid; 
                }

                $MM_restrictGoTo = "login.php";
                if (!((isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) && (isAuthorized("",$MM_authorizedUsers, $_SESSION['MM_Username'], $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'])))) {   
                  $MM_qsChar = "?";
                  $MM_referrer = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
                  if (strpos($MM_restrictGoTo, "?")) $MM_qsChar = "&";
                  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && strlen($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) > 0) 
                  $MM_referrer .= "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
                  $MM_restrictGoTo = $MM_restrictGoTo. $MM_qsChar . "accesscheck=" . urlencode($MM_referrer);
                  header("Location: ". $MM_restrictGoTo); 
                  exit;
                }
                ?>
                <?php
                if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
                function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
                {
                  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
                    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
                  }

                  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

                  switch ($theType) {
                    case "text":
                      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
                      break;    
                    case "long":
                    case "int":
                      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
                      break;
                    case "double":
                      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
                      break;
                    case "date":
                      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
                      break;
                    case "defined":
                      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
                      break;
                  }
                  return $theValue;
                }
                }

                $colname_rsRecord = "-1";
                if (isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) {
                  $colname_rsRecord = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];
                }
                mysql_select_db($database_dbConnect, $dbConnect);
                $query_rsRecord = sprintf("SELECT * FROM reg WHERE email = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_rsRecord, "text"));
                $rsRecord = mysql_query($query_rsRecord, $dbConnect) or die(mysql_error());
                $row_rsRecord = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsRecord);
                $totalRows_rsRecord = mysql_num_rows($rsRecord);

                $colname_rsCourse = "-1";
                if (isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) {
                  $colname_rsCourse = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];
                }
                mysql_select_db($database_dbConnect, $dbConnect);
                $query_rsCourse = sprintf("SELECT * FROM course WHERE email = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_rsCourse, "text"));
                $rsCourse = mysql_query($query_rsCourse, $dbConnect) or die(mysql_error());
                $row_rsCourse = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCourse);
                $totalRows_rsCourse = mysql_num_rows($rsCourse);

                mysql_select_db($database_dbConnect, $dbConnect);
                $query_rsCourselist = "SELECT * FROM courselist";
                $rsCourselist = mysql_query($query_rsCourselist, $dbConnect) or die(mysql_error());
                $row_rsCourselist = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCourselist);
                $totalRows_rsCourselist = mysql_num_rows($rsCourselist);
                ?>
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html lang="en">

                <head>

                    <meta charset="utf-8">
                    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                    <meta name="description" content="">
                    <meta name="author" content="">

                    <title>TACTSA Seminary School</title>

                    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
                    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

                    <!-- Custom CSS -->
                    <link href="css/agency.css" rel="stylesheet">

                    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
                    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
                    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
                    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
                    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
                    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

                <link rel="stylesheet" href="//blueimp.github.io/Gallery/css/blueimp-gallery.min.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-image-gallery.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo.css">

                    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
                    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
                    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
                        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
                        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
                    <![endif]-->
                <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>

                </head>

                <body id="page-top" class="index">

                    <!-- Navigation -->
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
                        <div class="container">
                            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                            <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                </button>
                                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top"><img src="img/logo.png"alt="TACTSA Seminary School"/></a>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                             <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                    <li class="hidden">
                                        <a href="#page-top"></a>
                                    </li>
                                                      <li>
                                        <a class="page-scroll" href="index.php">School</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="page-scroll" href="home.php">My Home</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#">Results</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#">Printout</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="page-scroll portfolio-link" href="#">Study Materials</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                      <a href="<?php echo $logoutAction ?>" class="page-scroll portfolio-link" >Logout</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

                            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
                    </nav>

                    <!-- Header -->

                    <!--End Header -->
                 <!-- Registration Section -->
                    <section class="headtext">
                        <div class="container">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                                    <h2 class="section-heading">STUDENT PORTAL</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </section>

                    <section id="registration">
                        <div class="container">

                        <!-- Form Submission Alert -->


                          <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                                    <h2 class="section-heading">User Profile</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                                <!-- Start Registration Form -->
                                 <div id="reg" class="col-sm-12">
                                 <div class="page-header">  
                <strong>Name:</strong>
                <div class="well well-sm">
                  <p><?php echo ucwords($row_rsRecord['fname']." ".$rsRecord['lname']); ?></p>
                  <p><strong>Gender:</strong> <?php echo $row_rsRecord['gender']; ?></p>
                </div>
                <strong>CONTACTS:</strong>
                <div class="well well-sm"> 
                  <p><?php echo $row_rsRecord['mobile']; ?> | <?php if(empty($row_rsRecord['email'])){echo 'N/A';}else{echo $row_rsRecord['email'];}  ?>
                  </p>
                  <p><?php echo $row_rsRecord['address']; ?></p>
                  <p><strong>State of Origin:</strong> <?php echo $row_rsRecord['state']; ?></p>
                  <p><strong>Nationality: </strong><?php echo $row_rsRecord['nationality']; ?></p>
                </div>  
                </div>
                <strong>REGISTERED COURSES</strong>
                <div class="well well-sm"> 
                                <?php
                                $cou = explode(',' , $row_rsCourse['courses']);
                                foreach($cou as $mark){
                                    $mark1 = $mark."<br>";
                                        }

                                    if ($mark1 = $row_rsCourselist['code'] ){echo $row_rsCourselist['name'];}else {echo "Failed";}
                                ?>

                </div>  
                </div>

                          </div>
                  <!-- End Registration Form -->
                            </div>
                    </section>


                    <footer>
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <span class="copyright">Copyright &copy; Tactsa 2016</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <ul class="list-inline social-buttons">
                                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <ul class="list-inline quicklinks">
                                        <li><a class="page-scroll portfolio-link" href="#privacy" data-toggle="modal">Privacy Policy</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a class="page-scroll portfolio-link" href="#terms" data-toggle="modal">Terms and Conditions</a>
                                        </li>  <li><a class="page-scroll portfolio-link" href="#faq" data-toggle="modal">FAQs</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </footer>


                <!-- Terms and Conditions -->
                    <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="terms" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                                <div class="lr">
                                    <div class="rl">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                        <div class="page-header">
                  <h1>Coming Soon</h1>
                </div>

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Return</button>
                          </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                     <!-- FAQ -->
                    <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="faq" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                                <div class="lr">
                                    <div class="rl">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                        <div class="page-header">
                  <h1>Coming Soon</h1>
                </div>

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Return</button>
                          </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                     <!-- Privacy -->
                    <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="privacy" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
                                <div class="lr">
                                    <div class="rl">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                        <div class="page-header">
                  <h1>Coming Soon</h1>
                </div>

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Return</button>
                          </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>




                    <!-- jQuery -->
                    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

                    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
                    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

                    <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
                    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="js/classie.js"></script>
                    <script src="js/cbpAnimatedHeader.js"></script>

                    <!-- Contact Form JavaScript -->
                    <script src="js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
                    <script src="js/contact_me.js"></script>

                    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
                    <script src="js/agency.js"></script>
                    <!-- Bootstrap JS is not required, but included for the responsive demo navigation and button states -->

                <script src="//blueimp.github.io/Gallery/js/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>


                </body>

                </html>
                <?php
                mysql_free_result($rsRecord);

                mysql_free_result($rsCourse);

                mysql_free_result($rsCourselist);
                ?>
```

Comment: remove the `mark1 = mark."<br>";` line and put the `if` statement in the `foreach` loop to start with...

Comment: Hi @Alex I did that but it echoed just 'a' in five places (aaaaa)

Comment: Yeah, try `if ($mark == $row_rsCourselist['code']) { echo $row_Courselist['name']; }`

Comment: Can I see the code before `$cou = explode()`? I want to know if you are getting this right out of the DB in some kind of loop.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the code in my question

Answer (score 0):

I used "rows" and "row" so that it more clear to see what's happening instead of the actual $row_rsCourse you were using. It's cleaner and will be easier for others to see. You will need to do a little editing to make this work, but you should get what you need. Remember you are using POST to get the value of the checkbox to PHP.

```
<?php

    // Set the value of your input to a variable
        $input_value = isset($_POST['your_checkbox_name']);
    // You also need to set an array of all of the rows in the database that have code, name, course, etc.
        $rows = your_rows_in_the_database;
            // for each row in the database that has a code, name, course, etc.
            foreach($rows as $row){
            // If your input value matches with $row['code'] of the current object in the loop
                if ($input_value == $row['code']) {
                    // Whatever you want to echo out
                    echo $row['name'];
                } else {
                    echo 'No matches were found';
                }
            }
?>
```

Comment: Hi @alex-rindone I tried with your sample but didn't work out well.

Comment: You most likely have to modify it a little to fit your needs, but that's the direction you want to go in. I saw you updated your source code so I can take a closer look later today.

Comment: @Jahswey, what does $cou equal? I am curious to see what it looks like in a var_dump.

Comment: I am assigning the strings i exploded from the database to $cou

Comment: sorry for my late response, been on the road since morning

Comment: can I see the var dump and die on $cou? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely helpful! See my above answer edited. Instead of trying to find out whether or not your value was in the string, you needed to find out if it was in the array.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks so much. Yes that is what i am trying to do. But I want to echo $row_rsCourselist['name'] for evey $mark that matches $row_rsCourselist['code']

Comment: How are you getting your checkbox value? I don't see that anywhere here. Essentially whatever your checkbox value is should be $mark1, so that you can then see if that was in the array of $cou, then you would echo out $mark.

Comment: My checkbox values was from a form input with type = checkbox
`<input type="checkbox" name="course[]" id="course" value="<?php echo $row_rsCourse['code']; ?>">` Whatever the user selects is stored in the database eg courses = RCS001,RSC002,RCS003 etc

Comment: I am not sure why your name and id are different. Here is a resource for you about checkboxes and getting values from the front-end to the back. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554758/how-to-read-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-php If you can only select one value for your situation, radio buttons would be better. By default, they will only be able to select one value where as checkboxes you would have multiple that can be checked.

Comment: I created room for users to select multiple options. that's why. Thanks for your support thus far