# PHP Undefined index... but it is defined

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I know there's a ton of these questions and I'm prepared to take the flak for asking another one as after an hour reading through them all I just can't see what's wrong. It's my first day using PHP so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

I'm using Twitter-Bootstrap and have set up a checkbox:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="mailing" name="mailing"> My label message </label>
</div>
```

In the php I have:

```
$mailing=$_POST['mailing'];
echo $mailing;
```

As well as a number of other POSTS. They all work fine except for this one which triggers the error "Undefined index: mailing in (my file etc, at line 14)"

The name 'mailing' is identical in the HTML and PHP, so what's going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the HTML and PHP code, so that we can verify that other input elements are going thru but only this giving problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried it with the checkbox checked? See [How to read if a checkbox is checked in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554758/how-to-read-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-php) - you should check the value with isset, because if the checkbox is not checked, there is not $_POST['mailing].