# How to get checkbox value if it is not checked?

Tags: php

I have a checkbox which is as follow:

```
<input name="bcmore" id="bcmore" type="checkbox" value="yes">
```

I am getting the value Yes, when it is checked, but what I want is to also get some value if it is not checked. So how can I get the value, if it is not checked in php?

One solution is like this:

```
$checkbox1 =  if(isset($_POST['bcmore'])) {
    echo "Yes"; 
}   else
    echo "No";
```

But is thery any other way to do the same?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554758/how-to-read-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-php

Comment: Expect it: `$bcmore = isset($_POST['bcmore']) ? 'yes' : 'no';`

Comment: @pedram, No, it's not answering my question because whenI do not check the box, POST will not show any value, and database will have a NULL value.

Comment: What  you wrote is not valid syntax, you can't use an `if` statement as an expression.

Comment: @Umar Using `isset()` is the correct and only way. Unchecked boxes are simply not sent to the server.

Comment: Besides, you shouldn't be inserting in the database till you done validation.