# Update DB value using switch element

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, pdo

I have an html switch to toggle between `on` and `off`:

```
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="togBtn" name="active" checked="checked">
    <div class="slider round">
        <span class="on">ON</span>
        <span class="off">OFF</span>
    </div>
</label>
```

You can check it live here: http://jsfiddle.net/tc4byzo8

It's checked by default `on`and it's inside a form:

```
<form method="post">
    ..
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" >
<form>
```

When the `Submit` button is clicked, I insert the data into the DB:

```
//Check if submit button is clicked.
if( isset($_POST['submit']) ){

     //Insert the data into the DB.
    $stmt = $conn->prepare( /* Insert query */ );
    $stmt->execute();

}
```

The DB has column which values could be `1` or `0`, So if the checkbox is checked, the value would be `1`.

How to check if the checkbox is checked or not to insert the values `1` or `2`?

I added the attribute `checked="checked"`, So that it's checked by default, But when I switch it off, The `checked` attribute still there.

Comment: How to check if the checkbox is checked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554758/how-to-read-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use php to conditionally declare the POSTed data like Anshul demonstrates.

You can modify the form with jquery before it is POSTed like Prakash Pandey demonstrates.

If you are happy to employ a simple html solution, then you can merely add `<input type="hidden" name="active" value=1>` before your checkbox line and add `value=2` to your checkbox input.

The magic is in the shared `name` attribute.  The hidden input field will act as a default setting which will be POSTed when the slider is set to OFF (the checkbox will not POST a value if set to OFF).  When the checkbox slider is set to ON, the hidden field's value will be overwritten.

*note, I am interpreting your question requirements to mean that you want `1` for **OFF** and `2` for **ON**.

Here is the full form that I tested my solution with:

```
<form method="post">
 <label class="switch">
  <input type="hidden" name="active" value=1>
  <input type="checkbox" id="togBtn" name="active" checked="checked" value=2>
  <div class="slider round">
    <span class="on">ON</span>
    <span class="off">OFF</span>
  </div>
</label>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" >
<form>

<?php
var_export($_POST);
```

Output for ON:

```
array ( 'active' => '2', 'submit' => 'Submit', )
```

Output for OFF:

```
array ( 'active' => '1', 'submit' => 'Submit', )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check value and assign it in if condition. Your code will look like below.

```
if( isset($_POST['submit']) ){
  if(isset($_POST['active'])){
    $_POST['active'] = 1;
  }else{
    $_POST['active'] = 0;
  }
  //Insert the data into the DB.
  $stmt = $conn->prepare( /* Insert query */ );
  $stmt->execute();
}
```

If you are facing any problem. let me know

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help do it same for toggle.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){ 
     if($(this).prop("checked")){ 
         $(this).val(1); 
      }else{ 
         $(this).val(0); 
     }
});
```

Comment: also by default you have to add default checkbox value to 1