# Update calculation based on checkbox in php

Tags: php

I have a calculation that makes a total based on an exchange rate, sometimes I want this rate to change based on a checkbox.

So my calculation is

```
<?php
if (!empty($sum)) {
echo ceil($sum / $line['rate'] * 10) / 10.0;
$sum1 = ceil($sum / $line['rate'] * 10) / 10.0;
}
?>
```

then if my checkbox is ticked I want it to change to

```
<?php
if (!empty($sum)) {
echo ceil($sum / ($line['ask_rate']+.02) * 10) / 10.0;
$sum1 = ceil($sum / ($line['ask_rate']+.02) * 10) / 10.0;
}
?>
```

This is the checkbox and update button, ideally when the update button is pressed it sees if the checkbox is ticked and changes the calculation if it is.

```
<tr>
    <td>Special Rate?</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="special" value="1"></td>
    <td>Press Update</td>
    <td><INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="update" NAME="B1"></form></td>
<tr>
```

The form submits to itself and totals up. But I'm having trouble working out how to make it happen.

Comment: To make this work, you have to enclose the `<input>` elements into a `<form>` element. Then, depending on the form action and method, we can help you with your issue.

Comment: it's in a form, the form submits to itself

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read if a checkbox is checked in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554758/how-to-read-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query for `isset($_REQUEST["special"])` to differenciate the to cases:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_REQUEST["special"]) && !empty($sum)) {
        echo ceil($sum / ($line['ask_rate']+.02) * 10) / 10.0;
        $sum1 = ceil($sum / ($line['ask_rate']+.02) * 10) / 10.0;
    } else if (!empty($sum)) {
        echo ceil($sum / $line['rate'] * 10) / 10.0;
        $sum1 = ceil($sum / $line['rate'] * 10) / 10.0;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
<?php

if (!empty($sum)) {
    $rate = $line['rate'] * 10;
    if(isset($_REQUEST['special']))
    {
        $rate = ($line['ask_rate'] + .02) * 10
    }

    $sum1 = ceil($sum / $rate) / 10.0;
    echo $sum1;
}
```

Depending on the method of your `<form>` (GET or POST), you can replace `$_REQUEST` with `$_GET` or `$_POST`

Comment: It's POST, I'll look up what REQUEST difference is from POST, it's working with REQUEST though