# How to get foreach checkbox value to a single variable with codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I parse from MYSQL into checkbox with foreach. But I want to get checked checkbox value from that foreach checkbox. So I could parse another record from MYSQL with this checked values.

I'm using CodeIgniter

```
<?php foreach($tb_pertanyaan->result() as $row): ?>
    <fieldset id="<?php echo $row->kode_pertanyaan; ?>">
        <h6 style="text-indent :2em;"><input type="checkbox" name="kode_pertanyaan" value="<?php echo $row->kode_pertanyaan; ?>"> <?php echo $row->pertanyaan; ?><br> </h6>
    </fieldset>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: can you explain more ?

Comment: share your complete code with view and controller.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554758/how-to-read-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-php

Comment: Please explain your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could just change `name="kode_pertanyaan"` to `name="kode_pertanyaan[]"` on your html form.
Then you sould get the records using selection method such as [where_in()](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=where_in#CI_DB_query_builder::where_in) :

```php
$kode_pertanyaan = $this->input->post('kode_pertanyaan');
$this->db->where_in('column_name', $kode_pertanyaan); // column_name is the column you want to fetch
$this->db->get('table_name');
```